# Jquery Resize Div with Toggle Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am building small private projects to learn jquery and currently I am stuck.

The Goal is to click a button and then my menu and my main content area should resize; when I click again it should resize itself back to normal.

The first part does work but the second part "jumps" down - I do not know why.

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ne1mb706/1/

HTML:

```
<div><button id="show_hide_button">click me</button></div>
<div id="some_box"></div>
<div id="some_other_box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#some_box {
    background: #fc0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
#some_other_box {
    background: #0cf;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

JQuery 3.4.1:

```
var collapsed = false;
$('#show_hide_button').click(function() {
    if(!collapsed){
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '0%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '100%'});
    } else {
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '25%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '75%'});
    }
    collapsed = !collapsed;
});
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start with the visible one to animate work properly:

```
var collapsed = false;
$('#show_hide_button').click(function() {
    if(!collapsed){
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '0%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '100%'});
    } else {
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '75%'});
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '25%'});
        
    }
    collapsed = !collapsed;
});
```